# How to get value of variable from open file

Tags: tcl

I am working on TCL script that will open another tcl file and I want to get value of variable from second opened file and use it in the first file.

Two file abc.tcl and xyz.tcl
abc.tcl opens file xyz.tcl and reads value of variable and use it in abc.tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `xyz.tcl` sets a global variable, `abc.tcl` will be able to see it if it used `source` to load in `xyz.tcl`.

Here's a simple example. This is `xyz.tcl`:

```
set SomeVariable 12345
```

This is `abc.tcl`:

```
source xyz.tcl
puts "The password on my luggage is $SomeVariable"
```

The `source` command is really very simple internally. It just reads in the contents of the file (into a string), and then internally `eval`s that string. Yes, this means that you probably shouldn't put `source` inside a procedure, at least not unless you're sure what the consequences of this are.